# Not able to inject Bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am trying to inject using a java bean . Its a very basic implementation however the injection is not working. Could you please guide me?

test.java

```
 public class TempClass{
@Autowired
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> newMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();


        public void setNewMap(HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> newMap)
        {
            newMap= newMap;
        }

        public HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> getNewMap()
        {
            return newMap;
        }
    }
```

Also:
for my bean config conn.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <util:map id="xyz" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="x" value-ref="x" />
        <entry key="y" value-ref="y" />
        <entry key="z" value-ref="z" />
    </util:map>

    <util:map id="x" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="xx" value="xx" />
        <entry key="xy" value="xy" />
        <entry key="xz" value="xz" />
    </util:map>

    <util:map id="y" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="yx" value="yx" />
        <entry key="yy" value="yy" />
        <entry key="yz" value="yz" />
    </util:map>

    <util:map id="z" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="zx" value="zx" />
        <entry key="zy" value="zy" />
        <entry key="zz" value="zz" />
    </util:map>

 <bean id="bean123" class="reference.to.class" autowire="byName">
      <property name="newMap" ref="xyz" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Could someone guide me as to what is wrong?

Comment: Where is your `someOtherBean` declared?

Comment: In this same file. Its basically a hashmap with <util:map id>
a key of which is referencing another map which sets the value.

Comment: I'll ask that you show it, but also show the error you are getting during initialization.

Comment: Your bean refers to `class="link.to.that.class"`.  Do you have it?

Comment: I have updated code. No error but the newMap is not containing any value after program starting :(

Comment: @neoeahit In the config file You don't have the `"xyz"` You have `x` `y` and `z` each being a HashMap; If you want to have them inside `Template` class, do the following.

In Configuration file
    
    `<bean id="newBean" class="Template">
    /*HashMaps as You created them*/`

in Template class
    
    `@Autowire
    HashMap<String,String> x;
    @Autowire
    HashMap<String,String> y;
    @Autowire
    HashMap<String,String> z;`

 Try and let me know, I have tried this solution last night and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I dont want to manually define the hashmaps x ,y,z because the xyz map bean may change, increase or decrease in side in future, so i want to make it flexible! Do I have any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The @Autowired annotation should be **above** the field you want to inject. And that field shouldn't be assigned only declared.

Also, injecting a map isn't the easiest example to start with. You should write a simpler test case just to get the hang of it. For example,

```
package test;
public class SpringInjectionTest {
    @Autowired
    private String injectThis;

    public void setInjectThis(String s) {
         injectThis = s;
    }

    public String getInjectThis() {
         return injectThis;
    }
}
```

And here's the applicationContext:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />   

    <bean id="testBean" class="test.SpringInjectionTest" autowire="byName"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that field shouldn't be assigned only declared"

Comment: The reference is assigned when you inject it. You don't need to assign the reference in the class (Java code) itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible fixes:

a. Declare your `newMap` as being of type `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` not concrete Hashmap, this is because internally `util:map` returns an object type of `Map` and autowiring will not be able to find suitable candidates.

b. Remove the `@Autowired` from `newMap` and instead inject the dependency directly through xml, the way you have done:

```
<bean id="bean123" class="...">
   <property name="newMap" ref="xyz" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Part Two Helped! It sovled atleast the bean beaing called!
The issue now is, how do i refer from first map's value to another map's key?